# kindly assist with sub report in Access which does not show data

Tags: ms-access

Need Assistance ..
i have created two report one is for customer service & another for parts details. here i am calling parts reports under customer service report . while creating report it shows perfect but when i click to report view i cannot see any sub report data but when i check part report individually it works perfect.

1st image while in design view
[image]

2nd image while report view
[image]

parts report view
[image]

Comment: How are the report/sub report linked?

Comment: via service Token No, under the sub report properties : Link master fields given source to Service Token No & Link child fields also given same source as Service Token no

Comment: hi kindly assist ..

Comment: If the two reports are linked correctly, then I can't see any reason why the subreport is not showing any data.

Comment: yes that is my confusion .. the report shows data in view mode but the same when i use as sub report and dont show in view mode ... anything can be done through vba